# Man in the middle using HTTPs downgrade to HTTP

Tags: tls, web-browser, http, man-in-the-middle, spoofing

In general browsers attempt to establish a HTTPs-Connection if possible. How would you force a browser to fallback to HTTP when somebody enters asdf.xyz in the search bar of his/her browser without specifying a protocol?

Therefore: sslstrip is probably not helpful as there are no links to "fake". **Furthermore, it is assumed that the site does not use HSTS.**

Assuming one can perform MITM - how would the routing with iptables be performed/which commands would you need to make the browser believe that HTTPs is not available and to fallback to HTTP?

Comment: Bypass for HSTS too with SSLStrip+:
https://github.com/LeonardoNve/sslstrip2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have a slight misunderstanding in the premise of your question.  If the site does not use [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security), and the user enters `example.com` in the address bar of their browser, the browser will default to `http://example.com`, not `https://example.com`.

See the following questions on security.stackexchange.com, and elsewhere on stackexchange.com, for more information on this behavior:

[Why do browsers default to http: and not https: for typed in URLs?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81801/why-do-browsers-default-to-http-and-not-https-for-typed-in-urls)

[Why is HTTPS not the default protocol?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4369/why-is-https-not-the-default-protocol)

https://superuser.com/questions/799464/how-does-a-web-browser-know-if-destination-is-http-or-https

This is precisely why we now have [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).  [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) is another attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Except HTTPS Everywhere does not even try to work "everywhere", since it uses a whitelist. There is a plug-in called "Smart HTTPS" that will try HTTPS on every site before falling back to HTTP.